# Html Image over image

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone tell me how can I add an image over another image without using `Z-index` or `Z-order`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Difficult to answer properly without knowing exactly what you want to achieve, z-index probably isn't what you actually need. For instance the following would work:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="img1" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" id="img2" />
</div>

#container {
    position:relative;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Also whether you use `<img>` tags or `background-images` depends on the semantic valueof the images, i.e. are they presentational or actualy content of the page?

Comment: I like all the answers... but I have accepted this one because it has the exact css I wanted :). Thanks all of you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The HTML is invalid without `alt` attributes on images.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way is to make sure they're both the same size, one has transparency, and you use this snippet:

```
<img style="background:url(image.jpg)" src="overlay_image.gif" alt="" />
```

Comment: overlay_image should be in the src attribute, not the background rule. Unsurprisingly, the background rule will determine the background...

Answer (score 5):

Set the main image's background image in CSS with the `background-image` property

Comment: This would probably be the faster way, but you can also position one of the images absolutely over the other one.

Comment: @Dan: yes, if you use background-position, though your overlay image needs have enough transparent space surrounding it for the underlay image to be visible.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use text over image by using the following code:

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0">
  <TR>
    <TD WIDTH="221" HEIGHT="300" BACKGROUND="samplepic.jpg" VALIGN="bottom">
      <FONT SIZE="+1" COLOR="yellow">Sample Text</FONT>
    </TD
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very "old school" code. Do not use this (except for HTML e-mail).