# Can we place image over an image in HTML?

Tags: html, image

Can we place an image over an image in HTML?

I want some image say a.jpg to place over image b.jpg.  Please tell if its possible in (only) HTML not in
CSS?

And if it is then how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What did you try?

Comment: Why don't you want to use any CSS?

Answer (score 5):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074914/html-image-over-image/1074940#1074940)

```
<img style="background:url(imageURL)" src="imageURL"/>
```

Example [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ICAZiGe/1/edit)

Comment: Can we use "style" in html? Even if we are not using css?

Comment: Absolutely, no problem. Visit posted exmaple bin :)

Comment: I don't know any way doing it without CSS either, but this answer contains CSS code... http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2

Answer (score 2):

You can use position to overlap two images?

```
<div>
   <img src="" class="a">
   <img src="" class="b">
<div>

div {
 position:relative;
}

.a {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0; left:0;
}

.b {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:0; left:0;
}
```

B Image will overlap A image.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to position things accurately one on top of the other is to wrap them all in a
 (div style="position:relative") and then use  "position:absolute"  and their top and left position relative to the surrounding div. 
When the relative div moves to a different position on the page due to resizing the browser window all the content within it including those that are  position:absolute  move with it.

Something like this could do it:

```
<div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
  <img src="x.png" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;"/>
  <img src="y.png" style="position:absolute; top:30; left:70;"/>
</div>
```