# How do I overlay images on top of other images?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay an image over another base image.
The images that I am using do not conform to a particular size but varies from page to page.

Each image overlay uses a style sheet similar to the one mentioned below:

```
#image1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44.594%;
    left: 30.642%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The base image uses a style sheet similar to the one mentioned below:

```
.base-image {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thus far, if the image is smaller than the screen size I don't have any issues.
If it is larger than the current screen size, the positions are relative to the screen size.

If I change the base-image position to absolute, I do get the effect I am interested in but the rest of my page becomes hidden under the base-image.

Is there anything in CSS that I can do to achieve my desired effect?

One of the fragments of a page:

```
<div class="base-image">
    <img src="Content/Images/baseimage.jpg" />
    <div id="image1">
        <img src="Content/Images/image1.jpg" alt="image1" />
        <br />
        <span>Some Text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="image2">
        <img src="Content/Images/image2.jpg" alt="image2" />
        <br />
        <span>Some Text 2</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The question is similar but does not address my problem directly:
[Html Image over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074914)

Their solution is what I have been using thus far for me to overlay the image. But for some reason, when the image resolution is larger than the screen size, the resultant overlay appears to be scaled down to fit the screen resolution. The image locations are therefore all wrong with respect to the base image.

Comment: Where is your code? what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried changing the position attribute in the `base-image` class from `position: relative` to `position: absolute`. While it does get the effect I want, the rest of my page is now behind the base-image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html Image over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074914/html-image-over-image)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can make a `<div>` with the same position properties as your current picture and then have the pictures inside the `<div>` have a `position:fixed` and then move the pictures as you like with `top:10%; left:10%` and etc

Hope this helps

Comment: I would have thought that `position:fixed` would make it relative the browser screen? Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Using `position:fixed`, my base image have floated above the rest of my page. And I have lost my scroll bar for some reason. So it doesn't seem to work for me unless I am missing something else. @herman-neple

Comment: What I am currently using is mentioned in the post but it does not solve my issue. @herman-neple