# HTML - Image over another image which triggers a popup window

Tags: html

I had a quick search for this problem and couldn't find anything that satisfied both parts so I hope this is ok to ask:

I am creating an interactive map which has an aerial image of a location as a background, with small icons overlayed over the top. These icons, when clicked should open a popup window with images or videos that have been taken in those locations, much like a google map.

I have found code to allow me to layer images over each other here:
[Html Image over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074914/html-image-over-image)

And I have found code for a popup here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup

And I can get both of these elements to work separately on my webpage, however I'm stuck as to how to combine them so that the image I have overlayed can be clicked on to trigger a popup.

It's been a while since I have coded in HTML and I can usually handle these kind of challenges but I'm finding myself a bit out of my element here.

Thanks!

Comment: go to this link:`https://cristianoronaldo.netlify.app/` go to its galley and watch its functionality if that works for you i can provide the code

Comment: I think that would work well, thanks. Would the images work in the format from the first link above? I.e. could I apply the code to the item with the id img2 in this code?

<div id="container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="img1" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" id="img2" />
</div>

#container {
    position:relative;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}

Comment: @criag yeah it should work

Comment: @criag `https://github.com/NutanPanta/Cristiano-Ronaldo` here is the link to the code